# Use mlr3hyperband with sobol sampling in the base stage

Tags: r, mlr3

I have read in the `mlr3hyperband`  documentation that on can define custom samplers (based on `paradox::Sampler`) for the initial base stage of each bracket. Now I was wondering if one could use that to implement some space filling design such as Sobol sequence or LHS for that. I have seen that `paradox` has `generate_design_sobol` and `generate_design_lhs` functions. However based on the documentation of `mlr3hyperband` I am struggling to see if that is possible, and if how.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We just discussed your interesting idea in the team. There is no LHS or Sobol sampler yet. The `generate_design_*` functions cannot be passed to Hyperband. But you could write your own `Sampler` class that generates LHS samples. The samples are always drawn before each bracket. With your own sampler you would get an independent LHS sample for each bracket. My colleague noted that it would probably be better if the sample from the second bracket fills the gaps of the LHS sample of the first bracket. This is technically not possible at the moment. We will discuss your idea further at the next workshop.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Okay that sound great. I think for now sampling each bracket with an LHS sampler (without connecting them), would most likely already improve the performance.  I will give it a look, I currently don´t really have experience with how to create an own `Sampler` but I guess I will find something in the documentation.

Comment: Let me know if you need any help.

Comment: Thanks! I had a quick look and at least for me it seems that this requires some time. I don´'t know when I will have this time, but thanks anyway !